# How to know if notification access is enabled/disabled

Tags: java, android, cordova

i just made a cordova plugin based on another one, i don't know Java so i have basic problems

When i use isEnabled function and the notification access is disabled the message displays: "disabled" (ok, cool), when i active notification access the message says "enabled" (ok, very well), but when i disabled it again the message still says: "enabled" ... please help!

https://github.com/martinciscap/notification-listener

Answer (score 0):

```
NotificationManagerCompat.from(context).areNotificationsEnabled(‌​)
```

Comment: It would be nice with some text, that explains your answer, maybe a link to also to docs?